# replace substring with dict value if the substring matches dict key?

Tags: python, dictionary, substring

I have a list of alphanumeric strings:

```
list = ["abc 123", "456 jkl"]
```

I also have a dictionary that contains substrings of the strings in the list above as keys:

```
dict = {"abc":"xyz", "jkl":"stu"}
```

I want to update the list using the dictionary so that the result looks like:

```
result = ["xyz 123", "456 stu"]
```

Basically, I want to replace any component (and only that component) in the list that matches dictionary keys with dictionary values.

I tried iterating through the dictionary + the list to do so, but I am having trouble updating just the substring. I would also like to learn more efficient/pythonic way of achieving this, please.

```
for element in list:
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        if key in element:
            element = value
```

Comment: Looks like your expected result is inconsistent. first , the key is replaced with value and in second value is replaced with key. It should be either of the below.. not mixed.       result = ["xyz 123", "stu jkl"]         or            result = ["abc xyz", "456 stu"]

Comment: Don't use names like `list` and `dict` for variables.  Those will mask the underlying builtin functions, leaving you severely handicapped and prone to bugs.

Comment: Did you look at `replace()` method of string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is like this? you must create a new list (based on your code)

```
list = ["abc 123", "456 jkl"]
dict = {"abc":"xyz", "jkl":"stu"}
newDict = []
for element in list:
    for key,value in dict.items():
        if key in element:
            newElement = element.replace(key, value)
            newDict.append(newElement)
print newDict
```

Answer (score 1):

You might get the result with list comprehension and `replace()` method like below -

```
l = ["abc 123", "456 jkl"]
d = {"abc":"xyz", "jkl":"stu"}
l = [e.replace(key, val) for e in l for key, val in d.items() if key in e]
print(l)
```

Simple loop will do as well.

But remember in this solution if any key of the dictionary present as part of the word that will be replaced as well. If you don't want that then you can split the elements of the list first to get the result. Or you can use regex to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> result = re.sub(
                     r'\b'+r'|\b'.join(dct)+r'\b', 
                     lambda m: dct.get(m.group(), m.group()), 
                     ','.join(lst)                      
             ).split(',')
# or
>>> result = [re.sub(
                     r'\b'+r'|\b'.join(dct)+r'\b', 
                     lambda m: dct.get(m.group(), m.group()),
                     item
               ) for item in lst]
>>> result
["xyz 123", "456 stu"]
```

Where,

`r'\b'+r'|\b'.join(dct)+r'\b'` joins keys of `dct` with delimter `|` to form the pattern string.

`lambda m: dct.get(m.group(), m.group())` creates a callable, that, if match found, returns value for that matching key from `dct` else returns the match as is.

`','.join(lst)` and `.split(',')` is a way to do this without a loop, only if your strings do not contain comma, otherwise some other delimiter can be used.